# Adding comment in same line and without sign

Tags: symbols, algorithmic

I use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\date{\today}
\title{Some Title}
\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    bla afdsdjkh
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Caption}
        \textbf{INPUT:} Some input\\
        \textbf{OUTPUT:} Some Output
        \begin{algorithmic}
       \State Function $UpdateNodes($x$)$:
      \Statex\Comment{ \%comment: Choose Representative decision tree \%}
                \end{algorithmic}
            \end{algorithm} 
        \end{document}
```

I would like the comment to be at the same line of the upper state and with no sign of little triangle and without the word 'comment:' besides. How can I do it?

Comment: ...but you do want the `%` signs? Is this a general update of `\Comment` that you're after, or only for this specific, single instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single instance, you can use `\CommentX{<comment>}` as defined below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\newcommand{\CommentX}[1]{\unskip~\%~#1~\%}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Caption}
  \textbf{INPUT:} Some input \\
  \textbf{OUTPUT:} Some Output
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State Function $\emph{UpdateNodes}(x)$:
      \CommentX{Choose representative decision tree}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Werner If I want not to represent the % sign, How can I do it?

Comment: @Avi: You can remove `\%` from the definition of `\CommentX`. However, there seems to be nothing that distinguishes the comment from the rest of the statement. You can also try `\emph{#1}` to `emph`esize the comment...

Comment: Thanks, How can I remove \% and put another sign instead?

Comment: @Avi: What other sign? Take a look at the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbol list](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive).

Comment: Any sign that I will decide for instance //

Comment: @Werner To add some space between the comment and the statement, a space `\quad` can be added like this: `\newcommand{\CommentX}[1]{\unskip~\qquad~#1~}`.